# vue style binding based on object value

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I am trying to dynamically style an element based on a pokemon's type (eg. fire gets a fire icon, fire/flying gets 1 fire 1 flying).

I tried to do it with a ternary operator and `:style` but it got really long and messy, so I'd prefer not to. Currently, I have it set as a method, and pass in an array, which look like this:

```json
types: ["water", "flying"] //or sometimes just one value eg: types: ['fire']
```

here is my method:

```js
methods: {
    typeStyle: function (types) {
      const backgroundImageUrls = []
      for (const i in types) {
        backgroundImageUrls.push('url(../assets/' + types[i] + '.svg)')
      }
      console.log(backgroundImageUrls)
      let backgroundPosition = 'center'

      if (backgroundImageUrls.length > 1) {
        backgroundPosition = 'left right'
      }

      return {
        backgroundImage: backgroundImageUrls.join(','),
        backgroundPosition
      }
    }
  }
```

and this is the html template it is called in:

```html
<li
class="card"
v-for="(mon, index) in team"
:key="index"
>
  <div class="cardfront-images"
  :style="typeStyle(mon.types)"
  >
...
</li>
```

but it's not working. I would also like to apply a 2nd effect, `background-position` and do `background-position: "center"` if there is 1 type, and `background-position: "left right"` if there are two. but I get an error because of the hyphen in the CSS property.

### EDIT

So I have it working to where it makes a `url()` for the background image (yay!), but unfortunately styling is not applied. So something isn't working, obviously. I have also updated my codeblocks to reflect changes.

EDIT2: So this solution did work, and I have given the check. For some reason, it didn't like my local assets being string-literaled in, so I just called the images from my git repo. Which I guess is good enough since I'm really just making this for my own education.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is to store all the background URLs into an array, and then join the array before the `return` statement.

With regards to the `background-position` property, remember that in JS all CSS properties are kebab cased, because `-` will cause JS to interpret it as an arithmetic operation, so using `backgroundImage` should be the way to do it.

Assuming that the `url` key in each object in the `types` array of object contains the actual path to the image, you can do this. [Note that you should really avoid using arrow functions when defining a Vue method](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#methods), because the `this` in the function will no longer refer to the component instance.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: function() {
    return {
      team: [{
        ability: "Keen Eye",
        name: "Wingull",
        id: 278,
        types: [{
            type: {
              name: "water",
              url: "http://via.placeholder.com/100x100?text=water"
            },
          },
          {
            type: {
              name: "flying",
              url: "http://via.placeholder.com/100x100?text=flying"
            }
          }
        ]
      }]
    };
  },
  methods: {
    typeStyle: function(types) {
      // Collect all URLs into an array with the template literal applied so we can use it directly in CSS
      const backgroundImageUrls = types.map(entry => `url(${entry.type.url})`);

      // Default value of background-position
      let backgroundPosition = 'center';

      if (backgroundImageUrls.length > 1) {
        // Example: you want one image on the top left, and another on the top right
        backgroundPosition = 'top left, top right';
      }

      return {
        backgroundImage: backgroundImageUrls.join(','),
        backgroundPosition
      };
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.cardfront-images {
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <li class="card" v-for="(mon, index) in team" :key="index">
      {{ mon.ability }}, {{ mon.name }}, {{ mon.id }}
      <div class="cardfront-images" :style="typeStyle(mon.types)"></div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Hmm. I will try this. Thanks for pointing out the arrow function thing. This was an amalgamation of several other posts and resources.

Comment: I was met with `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: _ctx.typeStyle is not a function`. I tried wrapping it in square brackets in the `template` region, but same error (im not even sure that's an appropriate solution)

Comment: @noscodemos What do you mean by square brackets? Did you copy and paste the function definition correctly in the `methods` object?

Comment: square brackets@`:style="[typeStyle(mon.types)]"` (since removed) and yes.

Comment: That's not how you're supposed to use it. Updated my answer with the basic data you've provided, it should work.

Comment: Oh I mean, I didn't copy paste it, but i did copy it and use my own asset folder for the images. the images in the API don't link to actual image URLs, just to another object with data about the type (whatever that may be). I have some SVG images I found that I want to use. `const backgroundImageUrls = types.map(entry => \`url(../assets/${types.type.name}.svg)\`)`.

Comment: Nvm... I cannot read my own spelling. spoke to soon. it's saying `cannot read 'type' of undefined`

Comment: hmm I'm still getting errors, but it seems to be due to issues that are not your own, so I will give you a check.

Comment: Shouldn’t you be using `entry.type.name`? Since `entry` is the argument used in the callback of the map function.

Comment: I have made some updates to my OP to reflect the changes, but yes I did notice that a short while after I posted it.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few different ways you can do this:

For conditional styling you can use dynamic classes like:

```
<div :class="{ mon.type }"
```

This will then automatically take the type name ('fire', 'water', etc.) on which you can use CSS if you'd like.

For rendering the icons properly, you will need to make some adjustments to the JSON object you give it.

But for that I would need to know whether you have all the information available or otherwise in what format you will fetch it.

I will update my answer when you let me know.

Comment: I pull them from two sources (the pasted team source and an API call to get the pokedex number (not relevant here) and the types) and combine it in a `store.state.team` array, which contains all 6 objects (1 object for each pokemon on the team).

Comment: Okay, that's more to work with. Can you edit your post to also show the structure of the JSON object of one pokemon?

Comment: I included an abbreviated example.